# express-handlebars: Linking to a handlebar using <a> tag

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I have created 2 handlebars files in 'Views' folder:

1. index.handlebars
2. contact.handlebars

I want to add a link to contact.handlebars in index.handlebars.

I tried using 'a' tag:

```html
<a href="views/contact.handlebars">Contact Page</a>
<a href="contact.handlebars">Contact Page</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Page</a>
```

but none of them is redirecting it to the contact.handlebars page.

Comment: You need to include the routes from which both files are being rendered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the browser cannot interpret a `handblebars` template, you need to link to the `route` in your server from which `contact.handlebars` is being rendered.

`<a href='/contact'>Contact</a>`

This is if your route on your server is at `/contact` for the contact page

Your express server should be serving two routes

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // render your index.handblars
})

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    // render your contact.handlebars
})
```

Comment: Ah I see, I had not declared the route for contact in .js file. Thank you.